# Spotify https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks return 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, spotify

I am trying to write a spotify nodejs/angularjs2 client to show a list of tracks but got 403 forbidden error. Authorization call and /v1/me/tracks call were following the guides. Scope for authorization was set to both all permissions (except for the mobile client related ones) and just user-library-read. Access token was acquired and send to /v1/me/tracks call as Authorization header. Please see code on http://www.github.com/tradrejoe/spotify-songslist.

1. The app defined 2 routes in /spotify-songslist/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts: login and songs.
2. Login goes to spotify login page passing user-library-read as scope, code was received as redirect url parameter. Then redirect to the /songs route.
3. Then "code" was passed along with client_id and client_secret as headers to spotify /api/token POST call in /spotify-songslist/blob/master/server.js, line 16, app.get('/atok'...).
4. Access token was parsed out as res.access_token on line 29 in /spotify-songslist/blob/master/src/app/songs/songs.component.ts.
5. Access token then was send as header to spotify /v1/me/tracks call in /spotify-songslist/blob/master/server.js line 68.
6. 403 status code was returned.

Thanks for your help.